# iOS Builds: This build is invalid in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, app-store-connect

I recently uploaded an app to the app store and its been processing for a few days now. I went in this morning to check everything out, and on the top bar of iTunes connect, i clicked on iOS builds to see how everything was going and I got a red circle with an exclamation point in it. When I clicked on it, it says "This build is invalid". Does anyone know the cause of this?

Comment: Do you have embedded frameworks? Possibly improperly signed/includes x86/x86_64 slices.

Comment: I got this problem once. My internet connection wasn't stable, so I guess something corrupted while transferring. Because I didn't make major changes between uploads. And next morning I upload new build without changes and it works good.

Comment: Yes I do. How would I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried uploading a new build ?

Comment: Okay. Well my internet is a little slow. I might just go somewhere else and resubmit. I have tried uploading a new build @Sudo and I just get the same error.

Comment: @Joe I don't have any frameworks in my Copy Bundle Resources and I'm still getting the same error. Its saying my GameScene binary is not permitted and if i delete it from CBR it won't let me call it in code.

Comment: Same problem here, no significant change but itunes connect shows that problem.

Comment: is there anybody knows the way to fix the problem? I try many things but cannot submit. The build is always "invalid". Thanks

Comment: I am getting same error.Is there any solution?

Answer (score 21):

Check your email, it tells you exactly what is wrong.  In itunes connect it simply says "This build is invalid" which is kind of useless.  If you check your email it will most likely be a testflight issue as you included the sdk in your build and its integrated into itunes connect now:

"TestFlight SDK - TestFlight no longer requires an SDK to enable beta testing, crash reporting and analytics. To continue using TestFlight, set up Beta Testing in iTunes Connect and remove references to the SDK from the following executables:"

Comment: Thanks you for that -- I had a completely different problem to yours -- but once I checked my email it was pretty clear what I needed to do (for me it was that I had added beacon functionality to my app and so I needed to set some sting in the .plist file to explain to the user why they should enable blue tooth for the app) ... uploading again now, fingers crossed this is the last barrier.

Comment: I have the similar issue here, however, I am not receiving any emails from the iTunes. I have double checked the emails which I have set for my iTunes account and also checked in the spam folder too. But no luck, no emails from iTunes.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem. I solved it by good luck after couple of hours of struggle. This issue was due to cocoa pods. Actually I installed "Alamofire" through cocoapods versions "0.38". I updated the pods for Alamofire 3.1.2. This build successfully got uploaded to the itunes connect but was declared as invalid in itunesConnect.

This reason was Alomofire 3.1.2 required cocoapods version 0.39. But I updated it using 0.38. So it was the issue.

Fix: Normal updating cocoapods by using the cpmmand $ gem install cocoapods, and then updating alamofire would not fix the problem. You will have to :
1. Update cocoapods using $ gem install cocoapods.
2. Delete the existing pod references from your project.
3. Reinstall pods using pod install command.
4. Done

Comment: Im not using cocoa pods.

Comment: Not work for me. I delete Pod folder, run pod install again. But the error still occurs.

Comment: Not only deleting the pod folder fixes the issue. You will have to remove all the references of the pods from your project. Remove pods from target -> build phases.

Comment: This was my problem also. Steps to fix: A: Comment out all pods in Podfile. B: pod install (this uninstalls all pods) C: gem install cocoapods (this updates cp) D: un-comment pods in Podfile & run pod install again E: Increment build number, Create Archive, Upload to iTunes Connect. Thanks for your answer - big help!

Answer (score 2):

You could validate the app archive trough Xcode and get details of what is the problem. The archives are currently found under Window->Organizer. To validate it you can click the "Validate..." button under the "Upload to App Store..." button. This may help you if you didn't get an email with details for the problem as was my case.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem too. and It turns out that I archive the build with Reveal framework reference. I think that's the problem.
In the pass, I made the same mistake and Xcode shows detail error info during uploading. Now it seems not.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem too. I write a App with Objective-C and use ios-charts(is swift),and I need to support iOS7,so it is troublesome... and when I upload app to AppStore I get the problem. I submit it again ,but still the problem. then I despair to clean the project and reset the codesiganature,what... that work! I just hehele ... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKCoe.png)

Comment: I am facing same issue with ios-charts...can you explain more on this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just Drag and Drop The `SDK` In folder include `info.plist` file which is not in use. That's create the issue for me. So find the unused `info.plist` file and delete it from the Source code. `Clean` the project folder and `Re upload`.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same issue on iTunes Connect and I received an email from apple regarding to TestFlight SDK that I forgot to remove from my project bundle. It says 'TestFlight no longer requires an SDK to enable beta testing' so after removing SDK clean the code, make archive again and upload. That't it!