# Unable to upload build from Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I am trying to upload build to App Store from Xcode 8 .I am successfully able to upload build  but on iTunes connect it is showing error message.

Error message : 
**This build is invalid.**

Here is ScreenShot:

[image]

is there any settings for Xcode 8 ? . Please advise me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't sure the issue. There are too many factors plz read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833105/ios-builds-this-build-is-invalid-in-itunes-connect

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2089652

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2089652

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Thanks for the above link. I forgot to add  NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist after adding description it worked.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Fan Zhang answer follow these steps and you can upload this archive use Xcode or Application Loader, whatever you want!

When you archived your app, find your archive in the Organizer, and then:

```
-->"Show in finder";
-->"Show package contents";
-->In the "xx.xcarchive" file, find the "Products"->"Applications"->"xx.app"(xx is your app's name), "Show package contents" again;
-->Finally, you can see there has a file named"Info.plist", open it;
Edit the value with a key named "BuildMachineOSBuild", I just change it to "15F34"(it's "EI Capitan 10.11.5" 's version);
```

This helped for me