# Ios Build display at itunesconnect is Invalid

Tags: objective-c

When I'm uploading iOS application it successfully upload from xcode, but when see at Itunesconnect it display as invalid Build. I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 and Seria mac os, I have tried many solution but nothing in result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app's `binary` gets rejected. Check your(**admin account**) email. Apple will give details of rejection in their email.

Comment: actually apple get back with email that Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at '/Payload/Appname.app/Info.plist' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.
Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Comment: for solving this i'm remove bundleexecutable key from plist file,but after that my build is not created at next time,and i'm not using any third party framework,is this problem occure b'cos of any  framework related?

Comment: Your projects contains more than one `plist` file. If yes, then *apart* from main target's plist file, delete the `bundleexecutable` key from plist. Check [reference here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35531360/988169).

Answer (score 0):

There may be some issue with your build that you uploaded to `itunesconnect` please check this link.

[iOS Builds: This build is invalid in iTunes connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833105/ios-builds-this-build-is-invalid-in-itunes-connect)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39826054/6438500

It may help you.